# How to run OSGi on Android 4.1?

Tags: java, android, osgi

is there anyone who could explain how to run any OSGi framework on Android 4.1. I found some tutorials but for older versions of Android or OSGi (e.g. Felix). Must of the information about running OSGi on Android is really old and I would like to know if anyone have tried it and succeed, or I should better run away from the idea.

I would like to have a solution less invasive as possible. I want to run a already developed software so I want to run it with the less changes as possible.

Any one wisdom about this?

PS:

I tried to follow:

http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/current/docs/android_dalvik_tutorial.html

and

http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html

Both tutorials wont work and are for old versions of android and their own software.

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually in the process of doing this. I've successfully installed Apache Felix on an Android device and ran simple Java programs. I followed the second link you have. The page was broken but I used a web archive to look it. Here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215091207/http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html) in case the one above doesn't work. If you follow that tutorial, you will at least get Felix installed. Just download the latest Felix, and the find the latest Felix Shell, and Felix Shell-TUI. You will need to Dex all three jars as described in the tutorial.

I created a folder on the Android device under /data/osgi/ and copied the felix/ directory there. The two shell jars should go into the bundle/ directory, and the felix jar can stay in the bin/ directory. Then I would create a script in felix/ that runs the following command

```
/system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar \
-classpath bin/felix.jar org.apache.felix.main.Main
```

That will start the Felix shell. You can type the command "ps" to see the installed bundles.

With all that said, I ran into issues when I started using third party libraries. You need to dex all bundles before installing them. This converts all class files into a Dalvik executable(dex) file. The problem with this is that some libraries are not native to the DVM. The first one I ran into was javax.xml.validation. This is something provided by core Java library. Well, Android doesn't run the core Java library. **So what do you do?** I was able to get past some, but not all issues by adding some configuration. I replaced the conf/config.properties file with [this one](http://pastebin.com/UB2Rjsm5). The important part of this configuration file is the definition of the Dalvik packages. Typically, this is where you export JRE packages to Felix so it can define them as system packages. Since there are no JRE packages, we need to define the Dalvik runtime and export packages.

You may need to change the Manifest file of some third party libraries too. Occasionally I get a library that complains about an osgi.ee version. When that happens I open up the jar and remove the requirement from the Manifest. I'll be honest and say I don't know if that is the right thing to do, but it resolves that issue. That should get you pretty deep down the rabbit hole. I am still facing problems with third party libraries playing nicely with Felix after being DEXed. Specifically parsing libraries, like Apache Blueprint, and Jackson. I'm going to try Knopflerfish this weekend to see if it is a smoother process...

Comment: Your answer bring inside to the problem. But is not viable solution for me. The software I want to deploy consist on hundred of bundles will take weeks to make all of it work with this methodology. Without taking into account that if I re-build the bundle I have to start over again. Anyhow I thank you for your answer.